# Why is prox parameter value not enforced in 6.2/reversegeocode?

Tags: here-api

Why does the `6.2/reversegeocode` API call not limit the results according to proximity parameter `prox`?

Example:

```
https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json
?app_id=my_app_id
&app_code=my_app_code
&maxresults=10
&mode=retrieveAddresses
&prox=53.468052,-113.44846,50
```

Partial result includes this record:

```
{
   "Relevance":1.0,
   "Distance":82.2,
   "MatchLevel":"houseNumber",
...
   "MatchType":"interpolated",
...
      "Address":{
         "Label":"125 Lee Ridge Rd NW, Edmonton, AB T6K 0N1, Canada",
...
   }
}
```

So my requested radius is 50m, but the distance to one of the results is 82.2.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

For Geocoder API v6.2 three aspects come into play here:

1. For performance reasons, distance filter does a simplified (plane triangular) distance calculation only, which for the higher latitude might be deviating  from the real distance (spherical calculation)
2. The returned distance is calculated towards the display point and might differ from the filtering distance which is the nearest of display or navigation point
3. Reverse Geocoder v6.2 uses a link-based spatial index only,meaning that radius is used to select nearest links within radius and from those
   the nearest point-address or otherwise housenumber range interpolated house number is returned.

I would suggest using the new Geocoding & Search API (https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-reverse-geocode-brief.html) Reverse Geocoder,  results are a bit more predictable and better understandable:

https://search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?limit=20&in=circle%3A53.468052%2C-113.44846%3Br%3D50&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY